# FSK Bandpass Filters for 900 MHz

Tags: rf, transceiver, passive-filter, fsk, band-pass

I'm attempting to design a basic FSK transceiver (architecture shown below) using only discrete components (transistors, diodes, resistors, etc). My idea was to separate the two binary frequency components via band-pass filters but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get such a high-Q (i.e. narrow-band) effect. Most filter calculators suggest capacitor values in the femto-farad range, which is not possible for SMT MLCC's. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is the very reason why people do not use the direct architecture, but use the quadrature demodulation method instead.

Comment: More practically, you do not want to *demodulate* signals at 900 MHz unless they have absurd bandwidth.  *Downconvert* your 900 MHz signal to an appropriate intermediate frequency (with today's IQ techniques that might even be 0 Hz) and *only then* demodulate.  You still might not chose a filter method, but if you do, at least the Q requirement will be reasonable.

Comment: I'm assuming downconverting after the LNA? The reason I ask is because the BFP181 LNA I'm using has better gain at lower frequencies.

Comment: *I'm assuming downconverting after the LNA?* If you need to ask that then you **really** need to study radio architectures a bit more.  Also, how much experience do you have at designing discrete circuits working at 900 MHz or even 100 MHz ? If the answer is "not much" then this system will be a huge challenge for you to get working. This is RF, it requires experience. Do you know how much inductance 1mm of wire will have ? If you have to look that up then you do not have enough RF experience in my opinion.

Comment: Why use only discrete components - that seems an unreasonable constraint and if you want help you should justify this constraint.

Comment: @FakeMoustache It was a little bit too late last night for me; of course downconversion should take place after the LNA because you need to amplify the low-power signals. I've designed a RF front-end for 900 MHz with the CC1310, but other than that, I do not have extensive experience. I'm an undergraduate EE and hope to pursue a career in RF.

Comment: @Andyaka Only discrete components is a requirement for the project, which indeed makes it more challenging. I've peformed simulations using QucsStudio, including touchstone files from components and coplanar waveguides between components to get a better idea of the link budget.

Comment: I asked you to justify the constraint.

Comment: *downconversion should take place after the LNA because you need to amplify the low-power signals* That's not a valid reason, mixers can work with small signals. Trouble is, your LO signal would more easily find its way back to the antenna without the LNA in between. Also an LNA usually has a limited BW, supressing signals you do not want to enter the mixer as they can end up at frequencies where you do not want them.

Comment: @Andyaka I should have clarified: the constraint is given by our professor.